# Почему идентификатор popen не определён, если он определяется в <cstdio>

Tags: c++, usb, hdd, ssd

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char* ATA_COMMAND = "atacmd";
const char* ATA_USB_2_0_COMMAND = "-d sat,12";
const char* ATA_USB_3_0_COMMAND = "-d sat,13";
const char* ATA_SATA_COMMAND = "-d sat";
const char* ATA_IDENTIFY_COMMAND = "-i";

bool executeCommand(const std::string& command, std::vector<std::string>& output) {
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
    if (!pipe) return false;
    while (!feof(pipe)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != nullptr) {
            result += buffer;
        }
    }
    
    pclose(pipe);
    output.push_back(result);
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    if (!executeCommand(std::string(ATA_COMMAND) + " " + ATA_IDENTIFY_COMMAND + " " + ATA_SATA_COMMAND, output)) {
        std::cout << "Ошибка выполнения команды" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    bool isUSB = false;
    bool isUSB3 = false;
    bool isSSD = false;

    for (const auto& line : output) {
        if (line.find("Transport: Serial ATA") != std::string::npos) {
            isUSB = false;
            isUSB3 = false;
        }
        else if (line.find("Transport: USB") != std::string::npos) {
            isUSB = true;
            if (line.find("SATA Gen3") != std::string::npos) {
                isUSB3 = true;
            }
        }
        else if (line.find("Rotation Rate:") != std::string::npos) {
            if (line.find("Solid State Device") != std::string::npos) {
                isSSD = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isUSB) {
        if (isUSB3) {
            std::cout << "USB 3.0" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "USB 2.0" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "SATA" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "SATA" << std::endl;
        if (isSSD) {
            std::cout << "SSD" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "HDD" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

По задумке здесь должны отличаться типы дисковых носителей, но из за невозможности использовать popen/pclose, задумка не осуществляется

Comment: Наверняка виндозные проблемы (ОС в метках вопроса указывайте)

Comment: Эти функции определены в GNU библиотеке. Если вы её и используете, то добавляйте ключ `-D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=2`

Answer (score 3):

Интересно, зачем у вас столько дублей?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Что до `popen()` — это все же не часть стандартной библиотеки C++. Если вы используете Visual C++, например, то надо использовать имена

```
_popen()  _pclose()
```